# What happened to Sham Nyaban?

Tags: one-piece

Somewhere between episode 12 and 14 of One Piece, The Nyaban brothers fight Zoro.
Zoro defeats them by using a sentoryu attack (i cant seem to remember the name) and sends The Nyaban Brothers towards the bottom of a slope. Buchi Nyaban gets hypnotised by Jango, but from that point on, there is no sign of Sham anywhere. Where did his corpse go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the story, both Nyaban brother's attack Zoro and Zoro fights with only one sword. Some time later when Captain Kuro comes to the slope, Nyaban brothers attack Kuro saying that they don't recognize him as their captain anymore. Captain Kuro then wears his cat gloves, scares both of them using Shakushi and orders them to kill Zoro in 5 min otherwise he would kill everyone. They attack Zoro, but Sham does not survive the 'Tiger Hunting Prey'.

But as your question suggests, Sham's body just disappears later in the [episode](http://watchonepiece.us/one-piece-episode-14-english-sub/).

- Here we can see Zoro attacking both of them.[image: Zoro Attack]
- Sham, as seen falling through Jango's glasses.[image: Sham in Glass]
- Sham not visible, can be behind Zoro's head.[image: Sham behind Zoro]
- However, we cannot see Sham's body in this pic.[image: No Sham]

The only explanation I can think of right now is that he slid further down than Buchi (because of really slim body and less weight). Since he was unconscious and seriously injured, some of Caption Kuro's crew members took him someplace else, to provide First Aid or something (a lot of time passes in between image 3 & 4). Sham brothers are their aces, and they wouldn't want losing him.

Comment: What you say is very possible, and it's the only answer that helps me out, so I think you may be right

Comment: Just a thought, there are no Kuro's crew members in the third pic. Where are they?

Answer (score 2):

Well if you watch further on you will see
**Spoiler**

> After Zoro swiftly dealt a finishing blow to the two brothers with his regained three swords, Buchi barely survived and was hypnotized by Jango for Super-Human Strength and recovery, to duel against Zoro once again. Zoro quickly defeated Buchi once again.

Answer (score 1):

Both the nyaban brother's attack zoro and fight on par with him. Some time later when Captain Kuro comes to the slope to see why they haven't attacked the village, both of them try to attack Kuro saying that they don't recognize him as their captain anymore as he was away or 3 yrs. After that captain Kuro wears his cat gloves and scaes both of them using shakushi and orders them to kill Zoro in 5 min otherwise he would kill everyone. They attack Zoro, but Sham does not survive the 'Tiger Hunting Prey'.

Comment: Captain Kuro does not attack them, just scares them. Then they attack Zoro, but Sham gets gravely wounded, unconscious (if not dead), unable to fight. Buchi survives the attack only because of his fat ([Episode 14](http://watchonepiece.us/one-piece-episode-14-english-sub/)).

Comment: well scares them by using shakushi. i don't remember how kuro responds but they attack kuro that's for sure.

Comment: He just uses Shakushi to get behind them and order them to defeat Zoro in 5 min otherwise he would kill everyone, but they don't survive those 5 min.